# Using RAND() keyword in more than one query at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql

I am querying a table by

```
SELECT tweetId, userName, tweetContent, tweetDate
FROM
 db.tweetentities
 WHERE applicationId = 3 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 0, 88 INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/theme_3.txt';
```

So, is it wrong to execute a same query in the same table at the same time?

I dont have much time that's why I  want to generate files as soon as possible?

Could you please tell me whether it will cause performance issues or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SGBD are supposed to handle multiple queries at the same time. You can worry about the "file writing" part, but the rand() keyword dont come with any drawback in this situation

Comment: What do you mean by file writing to worry?

Comment: You would have multiple processes all trying to write to `'/tmp/theme_3.txt'`.  That could be a problem.

Comment: Oh, no. I will write different files corresponding to applicationId. Of course, it would be a problem if I tried to write into same file. Thanks for your replies.